# Is there an alternative to javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was working on a program, I came to a point where I wanted to loop a value and then use it to test user's input with the if statement, but the problem was that I couldn't use the value of the loop.

At least that's what I think, then I tried placing the if statement as one of the codes that the loop statement is supposed to execute, surprisingly it worked, but when I tried more that one if statement (ie. else if), it only executed one of my if statement.

Please is there an alternative method to use?

Below is the code *(Input a Number between 0 and 10)*:

```html
<input type="number" id="i" />

<input type="button" value="submit"  onclick="result()" />

    <p id="k"></p>
```

```js
 <script>
 function result (){ 
 //first method 

    var x= i.value; 
    var y = 0



    while (y<10){
     y++
    }
     if (x==y) {
      document.getElementById("k").innerHTML = "correct"     
}
  / * it didn't work probably because the if statement assumes y to be 0. /*

 //second method 

         while (y<10){
    y++

     if (x==y) {
      document.getElementById("k").innerHTML = "correct"  
   } 
     else if (x >y ) {

    document.getElementById("k").innerHTML ="wrong"
   }   
   }
     //it only tested one of the if statement 
      </script>
```

Or is there another way instead of looping?

Comment: You know the correct value, why are you looping through anything?

Comment: `while(y<10) { y++ }`? What's the point of that? It's just a massive resource wasting version of `y=10`

Comment: Please if am wrong, tell me an alternative way

Comment: @Imran Just write `var y = 10;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

- The first instance the `if` statement is not inside the loop.
- Once you're done with the loop you want to exit it with a `break;`
- In the 2nd instance the `else if` block should appear after the loop. Why? For example the user enters `2`. In the first iteration of the loop `2==1` will fail, `2 > 1` will be true, but it's not the wrong answer. `x > y` is only the wrong answer when `y` itself is >= 10.

Instead of looping you can check if the value itself is greater than 0 and less than 10, you can combine as many conditions as you want e.g.

```
 function result (){ 
   //first method 

   var x= Number(i.value); // Number isn't necessary.
   if  ( (x > 0) && (x < 10) ) { // The && means "and", so if x is greater than 0 and less than 10. 
       document.getElementById("k").innerHTML = "correct";
   } else {
       document.getElementById("k").innerHTML = "wrong";
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks alot, I really appreciate

Comment: If an answer or comment helps, vote it up (click the up arrow). If an answer helps solve your problem, mark it as the answer.